# PHP array recursive function to group child values under root category

Tags: php, typo3-6.2.x, php-5.5

I want a recursive function to group all child categories under root category. I've an array like this;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [title] => Car
            [Child] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
              (
                [uid] => 3
                [title] => Color
                [Child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 5
                        [title] => Red 
                      )
                        [1] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 6
                        [title] => Blue
                      )
                )
              )
            [1] => Array
              (
                [uid] => 4
                [title] => Door
              )
        )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [title] => Two Wheeler
            [Child] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
              (
                [uid] => 7
                [title] => Type
                [Child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 9
                        [title] => Scooter 
                      )
                        [1] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 10
                        [title] => Bike
                      )
                )
              )
            [1] => Array
              (
                [uid] => 8
                [title] => Company
              )
        )
   )
)
```

My requirement is to bring all the subchild values to the main category child value. I mean I need the following structure;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [title] => Car
            [Child] => Array
                (
                  [0] => Array
                    (
                      [uid] => 3
                      [title] => Color
                    )
                  [1] => Array
                    (
                      [uid] => 4
                      [title] => Door
                    )
                  [2] => Array
                    (
                      [uid] => 5
                      [title] => Red 
                   )
                 [3] => Array
                   (
                     [uid] => 6
                     [title] => Blue
                   )
             )
       )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [title] => Two Wheeler
            [Child] => Array
                  (
                    [0] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 7
                        [title] => Type
                      )
                    [1] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 8
                        [title] => Company
                      )
                    [2] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 9
                        [title] => Scooter 
                      )
                    [3] => Array
                      (
                        [uid] => 10
                        [title] => Bike
                      )
                 )
               )
           )
)
```

How can I achieve this using a PHP function?

Comment: If possible; Instead of fixing your array afterwards, why don't you try to create your array the way you want at the first place ?

Comment: I can only able to alter this array. Thats why I asked for the help.

Comment: Let me give you a hint. Write a recursive function and use foreach with a pass by reference. You will see it won't be that hard. It will be fun. Good luck